# Update field (metadata) on a file with graph api version 5.9

Tags: sharepoint-online, graph-api

I am trying to update metadata on a file that I have uploaded using Graph API version 5.9 in C#. I am trying to use the sample I found here: [Update Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) but it does not seem to work for me. I am getting this error:

```
Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.
```

with this stacktrace:

```
at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter. <ThrowIfFailedResponse>d__28.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.<SendAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.<SendAsync>d__20`1.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Graph.Sites.Item.Lists.Item.Items.Item.Fields.FieldsRequestBuilder.<PatchAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
```

and I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

I have confirmed that the siteid, listid, and listitemid are all correct.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public Dictionary<string, object> SetDriveItemField(string siteId, string driveItemItemId, string columnKey, string columnValue)
{
    var list = GetDefaultListForSite(siteId);
    var requestBody = new FieldValueSet
    {
       AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
       {
            {
                columnKey, columnValue
            },
        },
    };
    
    var fields = Task.Run(() => graphClient.Sites[siteId].Lists[list.Id].Items[driveItemItemId].Fields.PatchAsync(requestBody)).Result;
    return fields.AdditionalData.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);

}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

please check if you are using the latest Microsoft graph .NET SDK. Since there is currently the [latest update](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#error-handling) to the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK: